# Collatz Conjecture: Is this the following a property of the minimum odd integer in a cycle

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, collatz-conjecture

Let:

- $k > 0$ be an integer
- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be the next $n$ odd integers in a sequence such that:

  - $x_{i+1} = \dfrac{3x_i+1}{2^{\nu_2(3x_i+1)}}$
  - $x_1 > 1$ can be any odd integer
  - $x_{max}$ be the largest of the $n$ integers
  - $x_{min}$ be the smallest of the $n$ integers
- $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$ be called a *cycle* of length $k$ if:
  $$x_1 = x_{1+k}$$
- $p_m, p_{m-1}, \dots, p_2, p_1$ be $m$ integers such that:

  - $p_m = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \nu_2(3x_i + 1)$
  - $p_m > p_{m-1} > \dots > p_2 > p_1 > 0$

Observation:

- For any $k$ odd integers in the sequence above there exists $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_k$ such that:
  $$2^{p_k}x_{k+1} = 3^kx_1 + 3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-1}3^{k-1-s}2^{p_s}$$

> Note:  Details for this can be found in step 2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079742/48606)

Question:

I am interested in understanding if there is a relationship between the ratio $\frac{p_i}{i}$ and $x_{i+1}$

If $x_1$ is the beginning of a *cycle* of length $k$, does it follow that if $\frac{p_i}{i} > \frac{p_j}{j}$, then $x_{i+1} < x_{j+1}$?

It seems to me that the answer would be yes so that the minimum odd integer $x_{l} = x_{min}$ would necessarily be related to the maximum ratio which would then be $\frac{p_{l-1}}{l-1}$

Establishing this has been a bit tricky for me.  I thought that an argument similar to John Omielan's [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3853486/48606) would do the trick but I am finding it less than straight forward to apply.

Am I right in my assumption?  If so, is there a simple argument to show that it is true?

The same argument should hold in a non-cycle for $x_i$ and $x_j$ that have the same starting point where $i \ne j$.  It may be possible to find a counter example in this case.  I have not yet found a counter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question about, even in a non-cycle with $i \neq j$,

> ... that if $\frac{p_i}{i} \gt \frac{p_j}{j}$, then $x_{i+1} \lt x_{j+1}$

A counter-example is $x_1 = 45$, with $i = 1$ and $j = 2$. Since $3x_1 + 1 = 136 = 2^3(17)$, then $p_1 = 3$ and $x_2 = 17$. Next, $3x_2 + 1 = 52 = 2^2(13)$ means $p_2 = 3 + 2 = 5$ and $x_3 = 13$. Finally, this gives

$$\frac{p_1}{1} = 3 \gt \frac{p_2}{2} = \frac{5}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, we also have

$$x_2 = 17 \gt x_3 = 13 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Thanks, John.  That's probably why I was having trouble completing the argument.